# Generating text from vector with counts

Tags: r, string, vector, text-mining

Here is my situation, let's suppose I have this data:

```
        freq
hello    1
bye      2
```

I want to create, from this data a string of this structure:

```
"hello bye bye"
```

I can do it using for loops and inelegant approaches. However my data can have up to 10000 rows, and is not only 1 vector I want to process. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line should work for tables, matrices, and data frames.

```
paste(rep(rownames(data), data[,1]), collapse = " ")
```

If you have other columns and `freq` may not be the first, you can use `data[, "freq"]` (or `data$freq` or `data[["freq"]]` for data frames and *dplyr* "tbl" objects) in place of `data[,1]` to be more explicit.

Comment: +1 But I’d suggest always selecting columns via `[[index]]` or `$name`, and never via `[, index]`. That way, the semantics won’t change when the class of the DF changes (for instance, `dplyr`’s `tbl_df` sensibly redefines `[` to set `drop=FALSE`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Good point.  I tried to cover all cases since `$` and `[[` can't be used on class "matrix" and "table".  I added `data[["freq"]]` and a reference to *dplyr* tbls